# how to use php dynamic Variables in paypal form

Tags: php, paypal

I want to use dynamic variabels in the form , I try to use like this 
`<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value=<?php echo $firstname ?> />` 
bu its not working, is there a anyway to use dynamic variable ? 
my point with this a when user login on my site and click the paypal button all those values gona be writen on paypal form .

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id=' $userid' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
$firstname = $row['firstname']; 
$lastname = $row['lastname'];`
}

$pp_checkout_btn .= '<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"><input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxxx@xxx.xx">
<input type="hidden" name="first_name"value=<?php echo $firstname ;?> />  
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value=<?php echo $lastname ;?> /> 
    .........</form>';
```

Comment: In your value you are missing the colon, is this a mistake when entering the code here or is this on your actual codes?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is the value empty? Do you get any errors?

Comment: its just a misstake when i put it here ,i have colon in orginal.not working" means Billing information

&lt;?php echo htmlentities($firstname)

Comment: $pp_checkout_btn .='<form... this is variable which use it to out put so i use echo, but not working.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what actually gets output when you echo $pp_checkout_btn to the screen instead of the code being used to generate that output?  I'm wondering if $firstname and $lastname simply aren't getting populated with the values you're expecting..??

Answer (score 0):

the only "custom" variable I believe that you can send using the paypal form is a variable named "custom" which will store a string for you.

from your question it looks like you want to pre-fill information for the user on the paypal site. in that case, there are form elements you can set for that. see here: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_prepopulate_outside

if you want to confirm payment on your site, and do something after payment is confirmed, you need to set up an IPN ( https://www.paypal.com/ipn ) on your site, which paypal will notify once it's confirmed.

Comment: thank you I have a paypal ipn fixed ,  I just want to use dynamic variable to pre-fill information for the user on the paypal site.

Comment: yes, I found the way by doing like this            
<input type="hidden" name="first_name"value="'.$firstname.'" />  
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="'.$lastname.'" /> 
 than echo out